# App terminated due to memory issue when no user is logged into Firebase after segue

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, firebase-authentication, nsurlconnection

The error happens when I check to see if there is a user logged into Firebase. If there's no user and I attempt to perform a segue or too much UI work, the app hangs and a moment later it's terminated:

```
Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue
```

Occasionally it will give me one of these guys:

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
```

I'm aware of the ATS settings in the Info.plist, and here's what mine look like

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>firebaseio.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

The strange thing is that i only get that error when i attempt to do something with the UI - like add a bunch of subviews or perform segues. This makes me think that maybe it's a threading issue or something not related to ATS at all.

Here's where i check for a user in viewDidLoad()

```swift
if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
    print("user logged in")

    // everything's peachy         
} else {
    print("no user logged in")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSegue", sender: self)

    // prints "no user logged in"
    // hangs and terminates if i try to perform a segue or add subviews
}
```

the segue is successful in that it reaches viewDidLoad() of the destination VC, however if i attempt to do any UI setup once it gets there, it hangs and terminates as well.

Been stumped by this for a few days now, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think your `setup` method is taking too long for updating UI. If you go through `ViewController` lifecycle, it is not advisable to put lot of UI changes code in viewDidLoad. Use `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` or minimize the UI workload.

Comment: ok, i see that, and thanks for the tip but it still terminates when it performs a segue. I've updated my question. any other ideas?

Comment: is it giving the same error?

Comment: it doesn't give the HTTP load failed error, but it hangs and terminates after a moment.